# overridePendingTransition with shared elements

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a custom animation between two activities with shared elements (the app logo). When I use `overridePendingTransition` while also using `ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation()`, the pending transitions don't get overwritten. When I comment out that line it works exactly how I expect it to

How can I use custom animations with shared elements?

```html
//This doesn't work
val logo = Pair(findViewById<View>(R.id.logo), "logo_small")

startActivity(Intent(this, when (activityToContinueTo) {
    1 -> Connect::class.java
    2 -> Delivery::class.java
    else -> Connect::class.java
}), ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, logo).toBundle())

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.zoom_out)

//This one does!!
val logo = Pair(findViewById<View>(R.id.logo), "logo_small")

startActivity(Intent(this, when (activityToContinueTo) {
    1 -> Connect::class.java
    2 -> Delivery::class.java
    else -> Connect::class.java
}))

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.zoom_out)
```